# Access and change array values inside class javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this simple code:

```
var num = [12,13]
class Test {
  constructor(num){
    this.num = num
  }

  change() {
  this.num[1] = 5
  }

}

test = new Test(5)
test.change()
alert(test.num[0] + ' x ' + num)
```

I am trying to change the value of `this.num` through the `change` method. However, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '1' on number '5'

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong here? 
Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nisalup/0sbxfhwL/2/), if it helps. Thank you

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, a number is not an array.

Comment: you pass `5` to the constructor of `Test`, a number is not iterable

Comment: It should probably be `test = new Test(num)`

Comment: yes. :))) thank you. my bad <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `num = 5` to `constructor`. And `this.num` will be `5`. `num` inside constructor is not refering to the `num` in global scope. Instead it creates a private variable `num` which is passed as `5`

You should pass `num` to `contructor()`

```js
var num = [12,13]
class Test {
  constructor(num){
    this.num = num
  }

  change() {
    this.num[1] = 5
  }

}

test = new Test(num)
test.change()
alert(test.num[0] + ' x ' + num)
```